# Movimiento con WASD con ncurses (No entiendo ¿por qué falla?)

Tags: c

Estando con ganas de estudiar un poco me puse a ver como usar la librería `ncurses`.
Para ver si había entendido lo último que leí me propuse a hacer un programa que moviera un *#* a lo largo de la pantalla controlado con WASD. Este es el código que tengo ahora:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ncurses.h>

int main (void)
{
        initscr();
        noecho();
        int coord_x = 10;
        int coord_y = 10;
        char direccion;
        mvwprintw(stdscr,coord_y,coord_x,"#");
        while (1)
        {
                refresh();
                direccion = getchar();
                switch (direccion)
                {
                  case 'w':
                        coord_y = coord_y - 1;
                  case 's':
                        coord_y += 1;
                  case 'a':
                        coord_x = coord_x - 1;
                  case 'd':
                        coord_x += 1;
                  case 'q':
                        break;
                  default:
                        continue;
                }
                if (coord_x == -1 && coord_y == -1) { coord_y += 1;coord_x += 1;}
                mvwprintw(stdscr,coord_y,coord_x,"#");
                if (direccion == 'q') {break;}
        }
        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

Pero en realidad no entiendo por qué no se mueve ni hacia arriba ni hacia la izquierda.
Yo creo que el error está en esta parte:

```
direccion = getchar();
                switch (direccion)
                {
                  case 'w':
                        coord_y = coord_y - 1;
                  case 's':
                        coord_y += 1;
                  case 'a':
                        coord_x = coord_x - 1;
                  case 'd':
                        coord_x += 1;
                  case 'q':
                        break;
                  default:
                        continue;
                }
```

Pero en realidad no estoy seguro de por qué falla.

Alguna idea de ¿por qué falla ?

EDIT: Veo que algunas de las respuestas sugieren que use coord_x--. Ya probe implementarlo y no cambia el resultado. Lo que pasa es que a++ , a = a+1 y a+=1 son formas equivalentes en c.

Comment: Creo que debería ser `coord_x++` y `coord_y++` en lugar de `coord_x += 1` o `coord_y += 1`

Comment: O también `coord_x = coord_x + 1;` y `coord_y = coord_y + 1;`

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues vi que editaste para colocar en tu pregunta la solución lo cual no es válido

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es que **no** has puesto `break` en cada `case`. El código equivalente al tuyo, usando `break` es el siguiente:

```
switch (direccion)
{
  case 'w':
    coord_y = coord_y - 1;
    coord_y += 1;
    coord_x = coord_x - 1;
    coord_x += 1;
    break;

  case 's':
    coord_y += 1;
    coord_x = coord_x - 1;
    coord_x += 1;
    break;

  case 'a':
    coord_x = coord_x - 1;
    coord_x += 1;
    break;

  case 'd':
    coord_x += 1;
    break;

  case 'q':
    break;

  default:
    continue;
}
```

Fíjate que hay dos casos que, aparentemente no hacen nada (`w` y `a`), que básicamente es porque las operaciones se anulan entre sí y dos que funcionan de casualidad (`s` y `d`), y digo de casualidad porque si hubieses puesto los `case` en otro orden el comportamiento habría sido diferente.

Después de poner los `break` el comportamiento debería ser el esperado:

```
switch (direccion)
{
  case 'w':
    coord_y = coord_y - 1;
    break;

  case 's':
    coord_y += 1;
    break;

  case 'a':
    coord_x = coord_x - 1;
    break;

  case 'd':
    coord_x += 1;
    break;

  case 'q':
    break;

  default:
    continue;
}
```